# Add menu item programmatically Drupal 6

Tags: 6, routes, navigation

I am trying to add a menu item to a custom menu programmatically in Drupal 6 and have almost gotten it but ran into a weird problem. I can add the item to the menu using the code: `drupal_execute('menu_edit_item', $item_array, 'add', NULL, array('menu_name' => $menu_name));
drupal_flush_all_caches();`
This somewhat works, but for the link to actually show up in the menu I have to either save the page twice, or save the page and clear the cache from Admin > Performance. Does anyone know why I need to flush the caches twice, or is there a better way to do this? Let me know if you need any more information, I included what I thought was relevant but I may have left something out.

Answer (score 1):

To add menu items use [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu/6):

> This hook enables modules to register paths in order to define how URL
>   requests are handled. Paths may be registered for URL handling only,
>   or they can register a link to be placed in a menu (usually the
>   Navigation menu).

example:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_menu() {
  $items['a/b/c'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example menu',
    'page callback' => 'example_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'your-custom-menu-name',
  );
  return $items;
```

}

To learn more about hooks see [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/6)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for a custom menu. I understand how hook_menu works. I need to add a link to a custom menu I created programmatically.

Comment: OK. see the edited post(menu_name).

Comment: hook_menu is definitely *not* for adding links to menus.

Answer (score 1):

The API you are looking for is [`menu_link_save`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7). And, as documented use [`menu_cache_clear_all`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_cache_clear_all/7) after.

Answer (score 0):

Try [menu_rebuild()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/6) instead of flushing caches.

> (Re)populate the database tables used by various menu functions.
>
> This function will clear and populate the {menu_router} table, add
>   entries to {menu_links} for new router items, then remove stale items
>   from {menu_links}. If called from update.php or install.php, it will
>   also schedule a call to itself on the first real page load from
>   menu_execute_active_handler(), because the maintenance page
>   environment is different and leaves stale data in the menu tables.